# convert array in php from ajax request

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [floor 1st Floor] => Reinforced Concrete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [floor 2nd Floor] => Plain Cement
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [floor 3rd Floor] => Plain Cement
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [floor 3rd Floor] => Marble
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [floor 4th Floor] => Marble
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [floor 4th Floor] => Wood
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [floor 3rd Floor] => eqweqw
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [wall 1st Floor] => Reinforced Concrete
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [wall 2nd Floor] => Plain Cement
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [wall 4th Floor] => Plain Cement
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [wall 3rd Floor] => CHB
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [wall 3rd Floor] => ewqewqq
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [roof] => Tiles
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [roof] => qweqe
        )

)
```

I have many array from ajax request and i get all of them in php what i did is i combine them and got the above result.My problem is i cant get all the value of the return invidually. How to convert the above array into like this below. So that i can get each value using the key example

```
foreach ($material as $value) {
echo $value['wall 3rd Floor'];
}
```

Or if possible how to get all the value from first array like this `echo $value['wall 3rd Floor'];`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [floor 1st Floor] => Reinforced Concrete
            [floor 2nd Floor] => Plain Cement
            [floor 3rd Floor] => Plain Cement
            [floor 3rd Floor] => Marble
            [floor 4th Floor] => Marble
            [floor 4th Floor] => Wood
            [floor 3rd Floor] => eqweqw
            [wall 1st Floor] => Reinforced Concrete
            [wall 2nd Floor] => Plain Cement
            [wall 4th Floor] => Plain Cement
            [wall 3rd Floor] => CHB
            [wall 3rd Floor] => ewqewqq
            [roof] => Tiles
            [roof] => qweqe
        )

)
```

i tried several approach like this one from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) but i didnt get the desired output

```
for ($i = 0; $i <  count($array); $i++) {
    $key=key($array);
    $val=$array[$key];
    if ($val<> ' ') {
       echo $key ." = ".  $val ." <br> ";
       }
     next($array);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to double `foreach()` it:

```
$new = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $new[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it as you like:

```
echo $new['wall 3rd Floor'];
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/298020)

---

Alternatively, if you want a shorter loop, you could do this via harnessing [`key()`](http://php.net/key) and [`current()`](http://php.net/current):

```
$new = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
    $new[key($item)] = current($item);
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/298023)

**Explanation**

- `key()` fetches the current key of the `$item`
- `current()` fetches the current value of the `$item`

Comment: sir i can get the value using the array `$data = [
  ['floor 1st Floor' => 'Reinforced Concrete'],
  ['floor 2nd Floor' => 'Plain Cement'],
  ['floor 3rd Floor' => 'Plain Cement'],
];` problem is when array is the first array example `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [floor 1st Floor] => Reinforced Concrete
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [floor 2nd Floor] => Plain Cement
        )
)`

Comment: @Pekka That's what I took it from. The first array you supplied. You have to create a new array the way you want it.

Comment: let me try it again sir maybe i got it all wrong, `$new['wall 3rd Floor']` this will echo the values `CHB` and `ewqewqq` right?let me check again sir

Comment: Hang on, you have keys that are the same. That's going to cause an issue as the value will be overwritten by the last of it's kind in the original array.

Comment: i saw the overwritten data how to avoid it getting overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:
    foreach(array as $key => $value)
    {
     echo $key ." = ".  $value ." 
 ";
    }